# Magento sending email after daily cron job completes

Tags: php, email, magento, cron

I have written a php script to do daily processing and would like to send an email to several administrators containing an html log file of the job process (which I'm automatically creating in the daily process script) confirming completion. Is there a simple way I can send the email by adding code at the end of script?.

Thanks
Mark

Comment: first you should share your code page  than we can help you secondly you can doit by PHPMailer.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $info = '<table><tr><td>Log Report</td></tr><tr><td>Stuff goes here</td></tr></table>';

        $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
        $mail->setToName('Joe Smith');
        $mail->setToEmail('joe.smith@whatever.com');
        $mail->setBody($info);
        $mail->setSubject('Event Log - ' . date("m/d/Y H:i:s"));
        $mail->setFromEmail('yoursite@sitename.com');
        $mail->setFromName('Event Log');
        $mail->setType('html');
        $mail->send();
```

Comment: Thanks, Exactly what I needed!